# Python3: call class from self?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I looked into splitting it up into multiple files so I can more easily manage various aspects of a class I have written. After googling and reading about it, I found this [tutorial](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyclassmulti.html) based on this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/comp.lang.python/goLBrqcozNY) quite simple. In short we just inherit classes without `init` functions and have all of those methods take `self` as an argument, as seen below:

## Set up

Directory structure:

- my_module/

  - .**init**.py
  - my_class.py
  - my_class_methods/

    - .**init**.py
    - _a_method.py

#### _a_method.py

```
class AMethod:
  def a_method(self):
    # do a lot of stuff
```

#### my_class.py

```
from .my_class_methods._a_method import AMethod
class MyClass(AMethod):
  def __init__(self):
    # etc
```

## Question

This works really well for me and I like it. If you are a more experienced python programmer (as I am just an average user) and you know of a better way to do this, please let me know.

My question stems from when the method `a_method(self)` (from `my_module/my_class_methods/_a_method.py`) requires the class which inherits it, e.g.:

```
### _a_method.py 
class AMethod:
  def a_method(self):
    # do stuff
    MyClass() # needs instance of MyClass
    # do more stuff
```

This setup will currently throw a `NameError: NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined` when the method `a_method` is called from `MyClass` (e.g. `MyClass().a_method()`)

How can I get around this? Would `type(self)()` work?

Comment: Why is the class 3000 lines long?!? First instinct is you are solving the wrong problem - refactor into smaller classes is the solution I feel!

Comment: What you are doing does not make sense to me. If you have a big class it means it is doing too much stuff, i.e. it has too many responsibilities. You should separate the responsibilities into **independent** small classes, and then have some classes/functions that glues things together. For example: user input should always be handled separately from "computation". You don't want a method that computes some stuff, then does  an `input`, then computes other stuff etc. It should be separated into a class that only "computes", and an other that asks the user for input and uses the former.

Comment: Obviously, without seeing your code we have no way to tell you how to improve your code. Also: reviewing code is not on topic on stackoverflow, but there is the codereview site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/   You may consider posting your code there and ask for suggestions (read the help center first!)

Comment: @KenSyme generally I agree and this class that I loosely speak of is a composite of many classes already (not just these stand in classes that contain methods). In the general sense it is hard to explain, but from my point of view (knowing the code) I can not see a clear way to modularize it further.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I agree and as stated in my above comment, the class in practice does do this. This class is basically a computation class, and there is a lot of computation. I agree that code review would go to the corresponding `SE`. However, the question here is not code review. It doesn't matter how large my class is. The question in short is, if I have a class I split into multiple files (as done above) and a method therein needs an instance of the class how do I reference it?

Comment: @SumNeuron I dispute that you cannot split the class into independent pieces of computation. As a professional developer I did write parts of complex software, but I never needed a 3k line class. Anyway: if you want to reference an instance you have to have the instance, so the answer is: you must pass that instance either to the method, or to the constructor of the class.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta perhaps my wording was not as clear as it should have been. Of course, there is the capacity to chop the code up further. However, in _my_ use case for this class _I_ find doing so not worth it as it makes some of the functionality more complex to implement. Again this is hard to explain in the general case and I am not saying you are wrong - only that I am of the opinion that I rather not split it further. Nonetheless I _do_ appreciate your feedback and insights as someone more experienced than myself. If you post your comment with a light example I'll give it the answer.